# Method getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated

Tags: java, android

I need to read an audio file recorded from the  microphone of the smartphone, and for that I'm using the code below:

```
 pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"audio_record.3gp";
```

The problem is that the method getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated at Android Studio (I'm using the version 3.5.3 and I didn´t indicated my API level).

There is another method that substitutes the getExternalStorageDirectory(), in other to not change my code so much.

Thank You.

Comment: When this sort of things happens to you, go to the official developer center ;) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio version is irrelevant. Depreciation is at the SDK level. [Docs say](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()):

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. **When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps**. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

If you are not targeting Q you can ignore this for a while as depreciation means you should stop using the method, not that it stopped working as of sudden.

> and I didn´t indicated my API level)

That's not true.

Answer (score 1):

> **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**
>
> This method was **deprecated in API level 29**. To improve user
>   privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is
>   deprecated. When an app targets **Build.VERSION_CODES.Q**, the path
>   returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps.
>   Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage
>   by migrating to alternatives such as
>   **Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT**.

For sample below code is older one. (deprecated)

```
val storageDir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pics")
storageDir.mkdirs()
```

We can use Context method as follows

```
val storageDir = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pics")
storageDir.mkdirs()
```

please check the following link more details

[Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment)

Answer (score 1):

I use the method below instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

```
 String getRootDir() {
        return ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null).getParent().split("/Andro")[0];
 }
```